# Magento 2 admin ui grid callbacks

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, requirejs, uicomponent

Is there any callbacks for admin ui grid ? For example, I need to call some js function after grid was fully loaded.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121478/gridjsobject-is-not-defined-when-add-grid-seriallize-inside-grid-ui I think it may help you

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem and **I have solved it by below code :** .

First create **Your_Module/view/base/requirejs-config.js** with this code:

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/form': {
                'Your_Module/form-hook': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now create a file **Your_Module/view/base/web/form-hook.js**

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (Form) {
        return Form.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();

                console.log('Hello ');

                function load() {
                       console.log("load event detected!");
                       var url = "https://[yourjs].js";

                       $.getScript( url, function() {

                       }

                 }

            }
        });
    }
});
```

This example extends the initialize method of the form component.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with initialize method was calling before the form fully loaded for me. I was needed a solution to manipulate fields once they are loaded. What I found is that `Magento_Ui/js/form/form.js` are using resolver for that case so I did the same.

Here's the code for the form-hook:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'rjsResolver'
], function ($, resolver) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Form) {
        return Form.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();

                console.log('Hello ');

                resolver(this.onLoaded, this);

            },
            onLoaded: function () {
                console.log ("name=" + this.name);

            },
        });
    }
});
```