# GridJsObject is not defined when add grid seriallize inside Grid UI

Tags: magento2, javascript, grid-serlization, uicomponent

I have face with this error while creat grid seriallize render data inside Grid parent. It build in by Grid UI Component. I dont use old way like magento 1. When click on edit tab to trigger ajax render grid. Console rise undefined JSObject. How to fix it and define missing object? Why it could happen

grid render by component grid follow path below but i don't understand it fully

> lib\web\mage\adminhtml\grid.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 admin ui grid callbacks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121432/magento-2-admin-ui-grid-callbacks)

Comment: Hey, I am stuck with the same issue. How you fixed that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. Somehow `GridJsObject` missing because template not render successful.
In Magento 2 grid in backend render by `grid.js` widget. 
Location of file in `lib\web\mage\adminhtml\grid.js`. 
File vendor\magento\module-backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\grid.phtml responsibility for render template. Inside this template you will find

```
deps.push('mage/adminhtml/grid'); for call widget
```

This line in 164-187 for creat GridJsObject by Object `varienGrid`

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsObjectName() ?> = new varienGrid('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getId()) ?>', '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getGridUrl() ?>', '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVarNamePage() ?>', '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVarNameSort() ?>', '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVarNameDir() ?>', '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVarNameFilter() ?>');
```

Grid missing by template not render